# jquery события выделения

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

У меня есть тег `<textarea></textarea>` в который с ввожу текст.

Как я могу отловить события выделения? Например когда я выделению слова мне выдаёт `alert('event')`;

Comment: по старинке [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3545105/1216425) поновее [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4367567/1216425)

Comment: Выделения каким образом? Я могу два раза кликнуть на слове и оно выделится, могу его мышкой выделить (держа клавишу)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский еще стрелки+шифт. но какая собственно разница, каким образом, хоть ctrl+A

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector("textarea").addEventListener('select', function (e) {
  var el = e.target;
  var sel = el.value.substring(el.selectionStart, el.selectionEnd)
  console.log('selection: ' + sel);
});
```

```css
textarea { width: 100%; height: 5em; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

```html
<textarea>Доброго времени суток! У меня есть тег в который с ввожу текст. Как я могу отловить события выделения? Например когда я выделению слова мне выдаёт alert('event');</textarea>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как в консоль кинуть выделенное слово кинуть жирным?